# Sending an explicit broadcast to statically registered receiver in

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to send a broadcast message from one app to another.

```
val intent = Intent()      
intent.setClassName("com.company.receivingapp","com.company.receivingapp.receivers.WakeReceiver")

intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES)
requireContext().sendBroadcast(intent)
```

Meanwhile the receiving app has declared

```
<receiver
        android:name=".receivers.WakeReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
    </receiver>
```

The following happens when I run this:
NOTHING.
No error messages.
No exceptions.
Nothing interesting in logcat.

I know that implicit broadcasts in manifests are becoming illegal. But what about explicit broadcasts in manifests?

All the examples I see are.

- Implicit broadcasts using manifest
- Explicit broadcasts using dynamically registered type

Is that because Explicit Broadcasts of statically registered receivers don't work?

Does that Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES actually do anything?

Comment: "Is that because Explicit Broadcasts of statically registered receivers don't work?" -- they should be fine. You don't need the action on either side, so you could remove those. You also do not need `applicationContext` to send the broadcast. "Nothing interesting in logcat" -- I think there should be a message stating that you are sending the broadcast. Are you saying that is not there? If so... are you really sure that you are going through that `sendBroadcast()` code?

Comment: Taking away action changes nothing. I've tried it lots of ways. Yes, it does get to sendBroadcast. I can step right over it or into it. If you know of code that works for this, I will follow it exactly.